# Formula Expression is required on the action attributes on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page which is hitting the above error - can anyone see what is wrong here?

```
<apex:page standardController="Task"
action="
  {!
    IF(
        $Profile.Name != "System Administrator",
        NULL,
        URLFOR(
            $Action.Task.Delete,
            Task.Id,
            [retURL="/007"],
            TRUE
        )
    )
  }">
<apex:pageMessage severity="ERROR" 
    strength="3" 
    title="Task Delete" 
    summary="You are not allowed to Delete Task records.">
</apex:pageMessage>
```

Comment: please note that the functionality actually works, it just displays the returl for the Sys Admin and allows delete; while for non Sys Admin they are prevented from delete and displayed the error "Formula Expression is required on the action attributes" obviously I would rather they saw the pagemessage error

Comment: Is it not working in only condition when you need to display the error in pagemessage?

Comment: @Ashwani yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write something which calls an action but that action actually does noting (not redirect). You will need to provide argument which is an action. Currently `NULL` is not an action so error is thrown.

Try this as well if it works.

Create secondary page to show message and primary page to delete task:

**Primary page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Task"
action="
  {!
    IF(
        $Profile.Name != "System Administrator",
                                                URLFOR(
                                                $Page.PageMessenger,
            Task.Id,
                                                [id=Task.Id],
            FALSE
        ),
        URLFOR(
            $Action.Task.Delete,
            Task.Id,
            [retURL="/007"],
            TRUE
        )
    )
  }">
<apex:pageMessage severity="ERROR" 
    strength="3" 
    title="Task Delete" 
    summary="You are not allowed to Delete Task records.">
</apex:pageMessage>
</apex:page>
```

**Secondary Page (PageMessenger):**

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:pageMessage severity="ERROR" 
    strength="3" 
    title="Task Delete" 
    summary="You are not allowed to Delete Task records.">
</apex:pageMessage>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I get the same error still

Comment: @Tobias try to wrote something `$Action` function which does nothing. Problem is `NULL` which is not a function.

Comment: @Tobias Just wanted to know. are you passing task id in url?

Comment: @Ashwani I am not a developer so I do not know how to answer your questions - I have some contacts who I will run this past and then if I get it working from your tips I will post the correct result back here. Thanks.

Comment: @Tobias I have updated the answer. Try the new solution.

Comment: @Ashwani thank you so much for your help it now works perfectly!